# Join on element inside array

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes where I have to use a value of one dataframe to filter on the second dataframe using that value.

For example, below are the datasets

```py
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import Row

cust = spark.createDataFrame([Row(city='hyd',cust_id=100),
                              Row(city='blr',cust_id=101),
                              Row(city='chen',cust_id=102),
                              Row(city='mum',cust_id=103)])

item = spark.createDataFrame([Row(item='fish',geography=['london','a','b','hyd']),
                              Row(item='chicken',geography=['a','hyd','c']),
                              Row(item='rice',geography=['a','b','c','blr']),
                              Row(item='soup',geography=['a','kol','simla']),
                              Row(item='pav',geography=['a','del']),
                              Row(item='kachori',geography=['a','guj']),
                              Row(item='fries',geography=['a','chen']),
                              Row(item='noodles',geography=['a','mum'])])
```

cust dataset output:

```
+----+-------+
|city|cust_id|
+----+-------+
| hyd|    100|
| blr|    101|
|chen|    102|
| mum|    103|
+----+-------+
```

item dataset output:

```
+-------+------------------+
|   item|         geography|
+-------+------------------+
|   fish|[london, a, b,hyd]|
|chicken|       [a, hyd, c]|
|   rice|    [a, b, c, blr]|
|   soup|   [a, kol, simla]|
|    pav|          [a, del]|
|kachori|          [a, guj]|
|  fries|         [a, chen]|
|noodles|          [a, mum]|
+-------+------------------+
```

I need to use the city column values from cust dataframe to get the items from the item dataset. The final output should be:

```
+----+---------------+-------+
|city|          items|cust_id|
+----+---------------+-------+
| hyd|[fish, chicken]|    100|
| blr|         [rice]|    101|
|chen|        [fries]|    102|
| mum|      [noodles]|    103|
+----+---------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the `join` I would [`explode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html#pyspark.sql.functions.explode) the array column. Then, [`collect_list`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list.html#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list) aggregation can move all items to one list.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = cust.join(item.withColumn('city', F.explode('geography')), 'city', 'left')
df = (df.groupBy('city', 'cust_id')
        .agg(F.collect_list('item').alias('items'))
        .select('city', 'items', 'cust_id')
)
df.show(truncate=False)
#+----+---------------+-------+
#|city|items          |cust_id|
#+----+---------------+-------+
#|blr |[rice]         |101    |
#|chen|[fries]        |102    |
#|hyd |[fish, chicken]|100    |
#|mum |[noodles]      |103    |
#+----+---------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new = (
  #join the two columns on city
  item.withColumn('city',explode(col('geography')))
  .join(cust,how='left',on='city')
  #drop null rows and unwanted column
  .dropna().drop('geography')
  #groupby for the outcome
.groupby('city','cust_id').agg(collect_list('item').alias('items'))
)

new.show()

+----+---------------+-------+
|city|      items|cust_id|
+----+---------------+-------+
| blr|         [rice]|    101|
|chen|        [fries]|    102|
| hyd|[fish, chicken]|    100|
| mum|      [noodles]|    103|
+----+---------------+-------+
```